# Performance of a Vaadin front end on Apache Tomcat

Tags: performance, tomcat, ubuntu, vaadin

The main form of my Vaadin application (running on Ubuntu server and Tomcat) takes enormous amount of time to load (more than 1 minute).

It's very simple and the web server is not under load (only a couple of users access this web server).

How can I find out why this performance problem occurs (and where is the bottleneck) ?

Comment: We had a similar issue, but it had to do with the database. Are you using a database to load data into your form or construct the form some how? Which DB are you using?

Comment: I got lots of OutOfMemoryErrors. Setting -Xmx via CATALINA_OPTS environment variable fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vaadin by itself takes just couple of kilobytes per application. Try not to load lots of views and data in memory upfront in init. Instead, do that lazily.

Comment: How can I load these views lazily? Basically, I have only one rather simple login page, and it takes lots of time for it to load. No OutOfMemory errors occur. Tomcat is running without problems (at least the management console works). So, I suppose that the problem is with my application. How can I find the bottleneck?

Answer (score 1):

I am also relatively new to Vaadin, but I can tell you this is not normal.  We are running our Vaadin application on both Tomcat 6 and 7 with only a few seconds of start up time (Mac O/S).  We deploy to Fedora for production.

Vaadin does take a lot of memory, and I would suggest that you check your Tomcat startup parameters to see how much is used and maybe increase it.  This is the -Xmx512m switch when you run TC or any java app.  I would say that 512m is really an absolute minimum for Tomcat/Vaadin for testing and 5 to 10X that or more would be used for a production environment.

Java memory defaults depend on your version of java and could be insufficient.

> Smaller of 1/4th of the physical memory or 1GB. Before J2SE 5.0, the
>   default maximum heap size was 64MB.